# Как передать переменную с одного контроллера в другой?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

`BaseController` имеет следующий код:

```
var viewModel = new BaseViewModel();
var claimsData = _dbContext.ClaimsDataUsers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserEmail == UserEmail);
if (claimsData != null)
{
    viewModel.UserName = _dbContext.ClaimsDataUsers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserEmail == UserEmail).UserName;
}
```

`PersonalCabinetController` наследуется от `BaseController` и создает свой объект `viewModel`

`var viewModel = new PersonalCabinetViewModel();`

Как мне в дочерний контроллер передать переменную `viewModel.UserName` из родительского контроллера?

Comment: Сессии в помощь!

Comment: что делает ваш матод в базовом классе и зачем что то передавать в базовый класс из производного?

Comment: Для ответа на вопрос недостаточно инфы. Приведите сокращенный код обоих контроллеров (хочется увидеть снаружи описанную функцию в базовом контроллере, и функцию в дочернем контроллере, где нужно получить `viewModel.UserName`

Comment: Спасибо за участие, разобрался, сейчас опишу ответ! А с сессиями попробовал - почему-то не вышло..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `BaseController` создаю переменную, в которой сохраняю нужное значение:

```
public string CurrentUserName { get; set; }

public BaseController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, 
                      ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    _dbContext = dbContext;

    var viewModel = new BaseViewModel();
    var claimsData = _dbContext.ClaimsDataUsers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserEmail == UserEmail);
    if (claimsData != null)
    {
        viewModel.UserName = claimsData.UserName;
    }
    CurrentUserName = viewModel.UserName;
}
```

а в дочернем контроллере `PersonalCabinetController`, присваиваю нужному полю значение этой переменной, после создания нового объекта `viewModel` :

```
var viewModel = new PersonalCabinetViewModel();
viewModel.UserName = CurrentUserName;
```

Comment: Зачем здесь (в первом куске кода) `viewModel`?

Comment: и откуда берется `UserEmail`?

Comment: и зачем два раза делается `_dbContext.ClaimsDataUsers.FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: public string UserEmail => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;

Comment: UserEmail определяется ниже

Comment: BaseController привязал к BaseViewModel которая ссылается на _Layout.cshtml нужно было, чтобы имя пользователя после логина(с гугла) передавалось в _Layout.cshtml

Comment: зачем два раза делается - да, не заметил, что забыл вписать переменную) Спасибо, подредактировал)

Comment: Именно так и хотел предложить сделать =) Хорошо, что удалось разобраться самостоятельно.